# Upload file submitted as link

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I want to give users 2 ways to submit a file to my site..

1) basic local->server file upload as follows...

```
<input id="uploadFilePost" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,.gif" type="file" class="upload" />

document.getElementById("uploadFilePost").onchange = function () {
      myFormData = new FormData();
      myFormData.append('postImageUpload', $("#uploadFilePost").prop('files')[0]);
      //ajax call to submit myFormData and associated validation
```

This is working fine, but I ideally want to reuse the approach if possible for point 2...

2) file upload by submitting a link (e.g. www.imgur.com/image.jpg).  To be clear there - I want to copy the file from the link to my server instead of just storing the link.  What I'm really hoping is that there's some way I can programatically associate the image.jpg link as a file to the input uploadFilePost (which would trigger the exact same process I've already coded for point 1).

Would really appreciate thoughts from anyone on whether that outline solution is possible (or recommended), and if so, what high level series of steps you'd need to go through to convert the image.jpg link into a file that could be programmatically associated with the input in order to trigger the upload.  Thanks!

Comment: Just a clarification - are you expecting the client to download the file to their local machine and then send it up to your server?  Or are you expecting your server to pull the file from the location that the client sends up to your server?

Comment: clarification continued - is the url submitted by your user the path to the image file or is it to a page that might have multiple images?

Comment: Hi Tim - I want the server to pull the file from the location so that the client doesn't need to anything more than submit the link to my site.  Hi Nocturns2 - it's an image file link so I don't need to worry about scraping a site for images and it will only ever be 1 image.  Thanks both!

Comment: Any ideas from anyone?  I guess what I'm really asking for is a cross-browser method to convert an URL into a file object - since from there I can simply reuse the code in point 1)

Comment: Might be easier to help if you post your current server code.  Effectively you'd just need to have your server make an http request for the binary file that you've been given the link to.